# Difference between x.toString() and x+""

Tags: c#, java

Back in college one of my profs. taught us to just do `x + ""` as a quick conversion from basic types to strings.
I don't remember which class it was in I had him for some Java and C++ courses(I haven't used either for some time now), but I use it in C#/.Net now which is what I'm primarily developing in lately.

Is there an advantage to using `.toString()` over `+""` for basic types such at int, decimal, float...?
What cases would `.toString()` be better?

Note:I was shown `.toString()` as well, that prof just recommended `+""` because it was shorter and I have just done that since then without questioning it.

Comment: Sometimes I am very thankful that professors are not working in public sector writing real code.

Comment: C++ tag removed, as this is most definitely not related to C++ in any way.

Comment: I *almost always* use `"" + str`. This even works if `str` is null, which is often -- but not always -- nice ;-) Note the order is not `str + ""`! C# and Java just have special "overloaded" `+` operator so they both work; not sure if all the answers below also relate to my preferred form.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think it would work in c++ but its been so long I wasn't sure.

Comment: I know this has already been answered, but a clearer method (if you don't know specifically what type `x` is) is to use `String.valueOf(x)` which internally does a `null` check and calls `x.toString()`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well, as a side note, it depends on what x is. If x is a primitive in Java, you have to call `.toString()` using one of its wrappers, like

`Integer.toString(x)`

I would say using toString() is generally better, because x + "", in at least Java, is saying you want to append the two Strings together.

Like in this example:

```
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
   int x = 3;
   String s = x + "";   
 }
```

That ends up, in bytecode, as :

```
public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
  Code:
   0:   iconst_3
   1:   istore_1
   2:   new #2; //class java/lang/StringBuilder
   5:   dup
   6:   invokespecial   #3; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder."<init>":()V
   9:   iload_1
   10:  invokevirtual   #4; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(I)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
   13:  ldc #5; //String 
   15:  invokevirtual   #6; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
   18:  invokevirtual   #7; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
   21:  astore_2
   22:  return
```

So it has to create a StringBuilder to append  "" and the String value of x together. While the efficiency lost isn't that much, it isn't too much to just use the toString function.

Compare with using toString:

```
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
   int x = 3;
   String s = Integer.toString(x); 
 }
```

Which ends up as:

```
public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
Code:
 0: iconst_3
 1: istore_1
 2: iload_1
 3: invokestatic    #2; //Method java/lang/Integer.toString:(I)Ljava/lang/String;
 6: astore_2
 7: return
```

And although it might just be my opinion, using .toString reflects what you actually want -- you want the String value of x, while using x + "" is kind of a hack and says -- I want the String value of x concatenated with "".

Side Note:
I can't speak on the intermediate bytecode C# would emit, but I imagine something similar to this. Plus, with C#, you can just call .ToString() on your value types just as easily as reference types, so I think my advice would apply the same.

Comment: What happens if you write it as `"" + x`?

Comment: Pretty much the same exact same bytecode. I can't speak for how .Net deals with it, though.

Comment: @Zach L, I'm sort of surprised the `"" + x` form would use a string-builder. I would have imagined this idiom would have been converted to a null-check and toString. Oh, well. In any case I would not make "for performance" the deciding factor for picking one approach over the other -- not saying there isn't a reason for picking one form or another :-)

Comment: Thanks, I figured there was probably more overhead.  I just wasn't exactly sure what it was doing.

Comment: @pst I totally agree-- 15 lines of extra bytecode is no metric to make decisions. I just think it should be considered that "" + x is not equivalent to toString.

Comment: The C# compiler recognises the empty string and optimises it away. It ends up calling `string.Concat(object)`, which in turn does the equivalent of `arg == null ? "" : arg.ToString()`.

Answer (score 3):

Honestly, I consider that kind of weird advice.

I can't speak to every specific case, but in general what `x + ""` will do in C# (which should depend on the existence of an overloaded `+` operator for either the type of `x` or `string`) is call something like `string.Concat(x, "")` which in turn will invoke `x.ToString` anyway.

In the typical case, this just means that `x + ""` has the overhead of one more method call than `x.ToString`. When `x` is a variable of some value type, however, this can also cause the value of `x` to be boxed unless an overload for `+` exists specifically for the type of `x` (this might be considered a useless point to make, as `x` will *also* be boxed in a call to `ToString` if its type has not overridden that method; this strikes me a a *bit* rarer, but it most assuredly does happen).

These are fairly trivial differences, of course. The *real* difference between these two approaches is that of readability; in my experience, `x + ""` is not very idiomatic in .NET and so I would be inclined to avoid it. That said, it could just be that it isn't common in the slice of the .NET world I inhabit, while there could be plenty of .NET developers out there who do it.

I *will* point out that while in Java, perhaps you had to write the unwieldy `Integer.toString(x)` for variables `x` of primitive types like `int`, in C# and in .NET in general all types (including so-called "primitive" ones) inherit from `object` and so have the method `ToString` (along with `GetType` and `GetHashCode`) available to them.

Comment: Thanks, I haven't really seen other people use +"" at all and for some reason it stood out to me today while I was coding.

Comment: `x.ToString()` for a variable `x` of a value type would also box `x` unless the value type overrides the method.

Comment: @Timwi: So it would. It's funny—I honestly hadn't even *thought* about the case where a value type doesn't override `ToString` as it seems relatively rare... which is funny, because I *had* specifically mentioned the case where a value type doesn't overload the `+` operator. Anyway, I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 2):

In Java, for primitive types (`int`, `double`, etc.) you cannot write `.toString()` because the types aren't objects.  This means that your options are either to write something like

```
x + "";
```

or to use

```
Integer.toString(x);
```

In C++, you cannot use `x + ""` to do this sort of conversion, since this will be treated as pointer arithmetic and will give you a bad pointer.  Using something like `boost::lexical_cast` is the preferred way to do the conversion.

And... I know nothing about C#, so I won't comment on it. :-)

Comment: Thanks, its been a few years since I've written anything in Java.  I guess I should have included Integer.toString(x); as an example.  Its been longer since I've used C++, someone else also corrected me on that point.

Answer (score 0):

There are no advantages or disadvantages of using `x+""`. `toString` is the method of `Object` type which implicitly called every time you add any object to string.

You can always override this method in your class if you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

Because strings are immutable, `x+""` invokes two functions: x.toString() and StringBuffer.append() (in Java, at least). I imagine most good JITs would simply turn that into a single function call, x.toString(), but I couldn't be sure without actually testing.

Comment: Or since it's a common well-defined idiom, could be replaced with just a null-check (for "reference types") and ToString.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter, really. It is very very unlikely this will cause any performance problems whatsoever. So it remains a matter of personal style.
Use whatever you or your team is comfortable with.

Answer (score 0):

In Java,

In addition to working with primitive types, `x+""` also works with `null`. Where `x.toString()` throws a `NullPointerException`, `x+""` returns `"null"`. Whether that is better or not is up to you, but it is a difference.

Answer (score 0):

In C# I would completely disregard this advice in favor of something more declarative such as using `.ToString` directly.

The only potential advantage this syntax provides you is it will create an empty string if `x` is `null`.  I would favor an extension method if this is considered an advantage in your code.

```
public static string NullSafeToString<T>(this T value) where T : class {
  return value == null ? "" : value.ToString();
}
```

The other reason to avoid this is because it can create precedence confusion.  For example do you know exactly what the value of `z` is in the following scenario without the use of reference materials?

```
int x = 42;
int y = 15;
string z = x + y + "";
```

Now same question with the following

```
int x = 42;
int y = 15;
string z = x + y.ToString();
```

The latter is more likely to be understood at a glance by the average developer who hasn't taken the time to memory C# operator precedence.  Hence I would prefer it because it has a lesser chance of being misunderstood.

Comment: This method already exists, it’s called `string.Concat(object)`.

Comment: Oh, also... you don’t need the `where T : class` constraint. You can actually compare `value` with `null` without the constraint, and it will just always be false when `T` is a non-nullable value type.

Comment: @Timwi, I realize you don't 100% need the constraint but there's also no need to use this method with value types.  I added the constraint to prevent the latter.

Comment: @JaredPar: Interesting! I would have expected `x.ToString()` to throw when used with a nullable value type, but it doesn’t!

Comment: @Timwi, nullable types are magic. Only wizards can safely use them :)

Comment: @JaredPar: I have no problem with them and I think I understand all their peculiarities (so they’re no “magic” to me). However, you’re not the first person I hear having difficulty with them, so maybe there is something unnatural about them and I happen to be compatible...

Comment: @Timwi, I think it's because I was a part of the language design for them in VB.Net.  As a result all I see are the crazy corner cases that baffle 90% of the devs out there.  As such I choose to avoid nullable syntax / lifting entirely for the good of the devs that come after me.